# How to use 'java' command options/arguments when executing JUnit tests

Tags: java, junit, classpath

I'm developing a C# application to run JUnit tests automatically. Since it's complicated to move the current location where my C# application is running, i need to execute the JUnit tests without directly go inside their folder.

So, i have this folder tree:

```
» ProjectFolder

»» ClassesFolder

»» TestsFolder

»»» testX.java

»»» testX.class
```

I'm already able to compile the files, using:

```
javac ...\ProjectFolder\ClassesFolder\*.java
javac ...\ProjectFolder\TestsFolder\*.java
```

But i can't execute the tests. I tried:

```
java -classpath ...\ProjectFolder org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestsFolder.testX
```

And got this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

I even try this way:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ...\ProjectFolder TestsFolder.testX
```

But, once again, it doesn't work:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: -classpath
Could not find class: ...\ProjectFolder
Could not find class: TestsFolder.testX

Time: 0,003

OK (0 tests)
```

So, my main doubt, is how i can use the options (like -cp or -classpath) of the java command, when executing JUnit tests using org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the jUnit-runner is not in the classpath you specify. You need to add the path to junit.jar to the classpath.

Google is nice http://www.jsystemtest.org/?q=node/44

But why not just use something that already exists and can take care of this? Like Maven or Ant?

Comment: Thank you, Tobb! I'd already set my classpath with junit.jar and another libraries that i need, but when i tried to use the option -classpath, i forgot to indicated it again. About Maven and Ant, i've read some articles about it, maybe i'll use it. Thank's for the tip. ;)